# CGAL compile error on parameterization '=': left operand must be l-value (#CGAL)

Tags: cgal

I am testing with CGAL trianglular mesh Parameterization, but I am getting some errors, First time I am using cgal, I couldn't figure it out what is causing the error.

I am getting Error: CGAL/Parameterizer_traits_3.h(203) : error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value

```
    #include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
    #include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
    #include <CGAL/Polyhedron_incremental_builder_3.h>
    #include <CGAL/Parameterization_polyhedron_adaptor_3.h>
    #include <CGAL/parameterize.h>

    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>      Kernel;
    typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>          Polyhedron;

    void Process()
    {
        TArray<FProcMeshVertex> tempVertices;
        FProcMeshVertex vert0;  vert0.Position = FVector(-50, 1, -50);
        FProcMeshVertex vert1;  vert1.Position = FVector(-50, 1,  50);
        FProcMeshVertex vert2;  vert2.Position = FVector( 50, 1,  50);
        FProcMeshVertex vert3;  vert3.Position = FVector( 50, 1, -50);

        tempVertices.Push(vert0);   tempVertices.Push(vert1); tempVertices.Push(vert2); tempVertices.Push(vert3);

        TArray<int32> tempIndices;
        tempIndices.Push(0);    tempIndices.Push(1);    tempIndices.Push(2);
        tempIndices.Push(0);    tempIndices.Push(2);    tempIndices.Push(3);


        Polyhedron poly;
        TriangleBuilder<HalfedgeDS> triangle(tempVertices, tempIndices);

        poly.delegate(triangle);
        CGAL_assertion(poly.is_triangle(poly.halfedges_begin()));

        typedef CGAL::Parameterization_polyhedron_adaptor_3<Polyhedron> Parameterization_polyhedron_adaptor;

        Parameterization_polyhedron_adaptor mesh_adaptor(poly);

        typedef CGAL::Parameterizer_traits_3<Parameterization_polyhedron_adaptor> Parameterizer; // Type that defines the error codes
        Parameterizer::Error_code err = CGAL::parameterize(mesh_adaptor);
    }
```

Comment: Building the CGAL parameterization example also gives the error

1. Parameterizer_traits_3.h(203) : error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
2. Parameterizer_traits_3.h(202) : note: while compiling class template member function 'double CGAL::Parameterizer_traits_3<Parameterization_polyhedron_adaptor>::compute_angle_rad(const CGAL::Point_3<Kernel_> &,const CGAL::Point_3<Kernel_> &,const CGAL::Point_3<Kernel_> &)'
Info         with
Info         [
Info             Kernel_=CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>
Info         ]

Comment: You said that even then example provided with CGAL gives you this error. What compiler are you using and which version of CGAL are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am compiling with Visual studio 2015.
CGAL version 4.9

Comment: Hi, I am using "https://github.com/armabon/UE4_CGAL" UE CGAL plugin, I figured out how to fix the error, but I don't know why it is happening, I am not really good at C++ template meta-programming, If I comment the line 'const double PI = 3.14159265359' and wherever PI is used replace it with '3.14159265359' it fixes the error. inside function 'compute_angle_rad'

Comment: I guess there is a PI macro defined somewhere outside of CGAL.